# kotlin RecyclerView list editing issue

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I do not want the lines separating the contact list to underline the profile photo

I shared the problem and the image I tried to do in the 2 pictures I shared below

there is a very simple error but I do not know the oki solution that appears I need your help

**PROBLEM**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5zfQ.png)

**I want to do**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6LnT.png)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_latest_message"
            android:layout_width="62dp"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username_textview_latest_message"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Username"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="mobile"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message_textview_latest_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:text="Latest Message"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


         </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/divider"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: At least show some of your code for the same part so that we can recommend changes or additions to it. Also, it would be better if you could explain a bit textually.

Comment: I know very little english so I shared the pictures so that they are more understandable

Comment: No issues about that. It is very much understandable now what you want to do. Upvoted for your quick edit. Hope someone can help you on this. :D

Answer (score 0):

You Need your Divider inside your Layout of the text and not under the whole layout. You simply put the divider 2 Layouts up, but i would recommend you doing such Things with constraintlayout, as it would be a lot easier to do. The Code for your changes are at the end of your XML

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_textview_latest_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="Latest Message"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <include layout="@layout/divider"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time, but that didn't work.